# Show points (datum) animated in map QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, time-series

I have a layer with points, in the attribut the points have:
Name
Number
Date
Longitude
Latitude

I like to display alla the points in a time series only showing one point at the time from first to lost point. They shall turn on and of after the order of date.
It shall be normal points not heatmap.

I have tried the earthquake tutorial with the heat map.but it's not the same type af data. What can I the.use?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/map_view.html#time-based-control-on-the-map-canvas https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#temporal-properties